# Weird glitch in suggested edit review

Tags: bug, review

I just reviewed this [suggested edit](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/27418).

Fifteen minutes later the item appeared again in the queue. So I reviewed it again and checked the queue. But I found only one instance. I found this [reviewed suggested item](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/27419) like I had reviewed it. I am certain I haven't reviewed this one before. So I wonder if it is possible due to a glitch that I have seen the same review twice but it was recorded as two different reviews.